# Rational $p$-adic integers and integers in $p$-adic field

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This is very basic question; if it is not suitable here, I will delete; but before deleting, it will be better, at least, if someone clarifies a little. In the book, Character Theory of Finite Groups by Huppert, the author take the subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{ \frac{a}{b} \,\,|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, p\nmid b\}$, and calls it the ring of rational $p$-adic integers (p.$467$-$468$); is it the same (isomorphic) as the ring the one considered [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicInteger.html)?

Comment: No the rings are different. It is more accurate to say that your ring is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$. The ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is in fact uncountable, so it cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, which is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ and is therefore countable.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. They are different.

- The ring described in MathWorld is the ring of $p$-adic integers, $\Bbb{Z}_p$.
- That ring is an integral domain, and a [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) of $\Bbb{Z}$ under the $p$-adic metric.
- [The field of $p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), denoted $\Bbb{Q}_p$, is the field of fractions of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Its elements have a similar description as power series of $p$, but this time we allow the lowest appearing exponent $m$ to also be a negative integer (so a finite point).
- We can view $\Bbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, and the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$ Huppert describes is the intersection $\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{Z}_p$, taken inside $\Bbb{Q}_p$.

Answer (score 2):

Usually $\Bbb Z_p$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers, the completion of $\Bbb Z$ with respect to the $p$-adic topology. What Huppert is doing here is considering
what I might write $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, the localisation of $\Bbb Z$ with respect to the prime ideal $p\Bbb Z$. Then $\Bbb Z_p\not\cong\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, since the first
is uncountable and the second is countable. But $\Bbb Q\cap\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z_{(p)}$
when $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z_p$ are considered as subrings of $\Bbb Q_p$ (the field of $p$-adic numbers). This, I suppose, justifies the use of the jargon
*rational $p$-adic integers*.

Comment: Gawrsh, I don’t see it as jargon. They’re $p$-adic integers that are rational numbers. Seems perfectly self-explanatory.